# QSplitter handle bar

Tags: python, pyqt, qsplitter

I am using python 2.6 and compatible PyQt4 version 4.5.3, In my window i am using QSplitter for two QTableWidget but 
i am not able to find the split bar between two widgets. but in Autodesk Maya software the splitter is having a handle as dots.
Can anyone help me in acheveing that in PyQt window. image is attached for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize a `QSplitter` using stylesheets: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qsplitter